# How to migrate Kafka topic used in a standalone Kafka server to Kafka cluster with replication-factor 2?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm running a standalone Kafka server with multiple producers and consumers. Now I want to implement Kafka cluster by adding another broker. How can I do this by using same topic with replication-factor.

Answer (score 0):

Now you are moving to a cluster having two kafka brokers then you should increase the number of partitions to two using the following commands.

```
kafka-topics --topic my-topic --alter --partitions 2 --zookeeper zoo1
```

# Observe partitions with Number of partition 2 and RF: 1

```
kafka-topics --topic my-topic --describe  --zookeeper zoo1

Topic:my-topic PartitionCount:2 ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:

 Topic: my-topic Partition: 0 Leader: 0 Replicas: 1 Isr: 0
 Topic: my-topic Partition: 1 Leader: 2 Replicas: 1 Isr: 1
```

Increasing the replication factor of an existing topic is easy.Need to specify the extra replicas in the custom reassignment json file and use it with --execute option.

Create increase-replication-factor.json

```
   {"version":1,
  "partitions":[
     {"topic":"my-topic","partition":0,"replicas":[0,1]},
     {"topic":"my-topic","partition":1,"replicas":[0,1]}
]}
```

Execute the following command

```
kafka-reassign-partitions --zookeeper localhost:2181 --reassignment-json-file increase-replication-factor.json --execute
```

You can verify the replicas using the following command.

```
kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic my-topic --describe

Topic: my-topic Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0,1 Isr: 0,1
Topic: my-topic Partition: 1    Leader: 1   Replicas: 0,1 Isr: 0,1
```

I would suggest you to go through the following link to redistribute the data on two partitions equally.

https://labs.tabmo.io/rebalancing-kafkas-partitions-803918d8d244
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_increase_replication_factor

Hope it will be helpful to you.